# JQuery - Save html from elements and restore it

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to replace the text of a button, while maintaining its size.
Everything seems to work fine, but unfortunately when restoring its original text
this seems to occupy more space.

HTML

```
<form id='form-1'>
  <div class="bttn wt">
    <i class="fa fa-at"></i>
    <label>REQUEST LOST PASSWORD</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.bttn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JQ

```
$('.bttn').on('click', function()
{
   var bt = $('#form-1').find('.wt');
   var bt_wd = $(bt).width();
   var bt_ori = $(bt).html().trim();
   var bt_wait = $(bt).html('WAITING..').width(bt_wd);

   setTimeout(function() 
   {
       $(bt).width(bt_wd).html(bt_ori);
   }, 3000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0h9f127r/)

What causes this problem? How can I solve?
Thanks

Comment: Not seeing the issue...what am I missing? Label element does not change size on restoring in dev tools

Comment: @Paulie_D - Have you seen my example?

Comment: Yep...no change as stated.

Comment: @Paulie_D - With firefox and IE see problems

Comment: You might want to mention that in your question. I'm on **Chrome Version 38.0.2125.101 m (64-bit)** BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you use `$(bt).css('width', 'auto').html(bt_ori);`.

Comment: In this way is correct! but I do not understand why it takes up more space. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but it has something to do with padding (2x15px). `bt_wd` evaluates to 206, but if you look at the DOM, the width that is applied on `bt_wait` is `width: 236px;`. Anyway, `$(bt).css('width', 'auto')` sets it back to default.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the jQuery width() method.

By default jQuery width() method round the width. In this context the actual with of bttn element is "236.109375px".

When we get the width of this by using jquery it is rounding it to "236px".

So we have to add the width 237px on the css as below.

```
width: 237px;
```

And we need to remove the width() from jquery.

```
$('.bttn').on('click', function()
{
    var bt = $('#form-1').find('.wt');
    var bt_ori = $(bt).html().trim();
    var bt_wait = $(bt).html('WAITING..');

    setTimeout(function() 
    {
       $(bt).html(bt_ori);
    }, 3000);
});
```